# FILE * pointer as argument by reference C

Tags: c

I want to pass `FILE*` as an argument to a function to modify it for reuse later.
Example:

```
void main () {
   FILE *file = NULL;
   int getFile(file);
   printf("file from main is :%x", file);
   // here i want to use fread ...etc
}
int getFile(FILE *f) {
  FILE *fp = fopen("myfile.dat", "rb");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("failed to open file\n");
    return 1;
  }
  f = fp;
  printf("fp is :%x", fp);
  printf("file from getFile  is :%x", f);
  return 0;
}
```

This code outputs:

```
 fp is: e40009b0
 file from getFile is: e40009b0
 file from main is : 0
```

as you can see, the address of file is not changed (`NULL`). How I can change it in function the `getFile()` ?.
Thank you

Comment: `file = fp;` what is this?

Comment: I think you need a pointer-pointer

Comment: "This code return".. not sure how, there are many errors: http://ideone.com/KpTFfw

Comment: there was a typo error, sorry. f=fp instaed of file=fp

Comment: There's still a typo in the `printf`. You should always check your code before posting it. See [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), especially the **verifiable** part.

Comment: Please, please compile and test your actual MCVE and post what you have tested.  Anything else wastes everyone's time:(

Comment: The code is OK now, and there is solution in duplicated question ;).